# What is the difference between $A^TA$ and $A^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transpose

What is the difference between squaring a matrix by multiplying it by its transpose and squaring it by multiplying it by itself. When I am asked to square a matrix, which method is preferred?

Comment: "squaring" means multiplying it by itself.

Comment: When you are asked to square a matrix you perform $A^2=A\cdot A$. If $A$ is symmetric, either is fine. If $A$ is $m\times n$, then $A^tA$ is $n\times n$, but squaring it isn't possible.

Comment: What is the difference?  The one is $A^T \cdot A$ while the other is $A\cdot A$...  Notice in particular that $A^T$ is not necessarily equal to $A$ so they represent different products.  This is like asking "What is the difference between $A\cdot B$ and $A^T\cdot B$"... they obviously represent different things because the terms in the product are different.  As for what "squaring a matrix" refers to... $A^2 = A\cdot A$.

Comment: I could have swore this exact question was posted before in the last few weeks, but can't seem to find it. Perhaps it was deleted and reposted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general we have $A^TA \ne A^2.$

Example: $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$

Answer (score 1):

In the special case that $A$ is an invertible square matrix, we have
$$A^T A = A^2 \iff (A^T A) A^{-1} = (A^2)A^{-1} \iff A^T = A \iff \text{$A$ is symmetric}
$$
So, for example, $A=\pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ -1 & 1}$ is invertible (because its determinant is not zero) and not symmetric (obviously), hence $A^T A \ne A^2$ for this example (which an easy calculation shows).

For another example, $A = \pmatrix{1.49 & 98.07 \\ 3.6 & -47.458}$ is also invertible (because its determinant is obviously negative) and not symmetric (obviously), hence $A^T \ne A^2$ (which a hard calculation shows).

Answer (score 0):

Matrix multiplication fails in some cases for example:
Take matrices $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$, $
A^T=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$.You can find $A.A^T$ but you cannot find $A^2$?